# Show seekbar when video is uploaded to firebase in android

Tags: android, firebase, video, seekbar

```
floatingActionButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                intent.setType("video/*");
                intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_LOCAL_ONLY, true);
                startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Complete action using"), RC_PHOTO_PICKER);

            }
        });

@Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
         if (requestCode == RC_PHOTO_PICKER && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();

            // Get a reference to store file at chat_photos/<FILENAME>
            StorageReference photoRef = mChatPhotosStorageReference.child(selectedImageUri.getLastPathSegment());

            // Upload file to Firebase Storage
            photoRef.putFile(selectedImageUri)
                    .addOnSuccessListener(this, new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                        public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                            // When the image has successfully uploaded, we get its download URL
                            //  progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            Uri downloadUrl = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl();

                            // Set the download URL to the message box, so that the user can send it to the database
                            Video video = new Video(downloadUrl.toString());
                            mMessagesDatabaseReference.push().setValue(video);
                        }
                    });
        }
    }
```

I want to show progress on seekbar when image is uploading as a notification. How do I do that? I have created an object of Seekbar in my `onCreate`. How to get duration of the video which I am uploading and show the seekbar in notification and the user should not be able to swipe notification when upload starts? Please help.

Comment: check out this question's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37457152/how-to-show-progress-bar-status-by-percentage-while-uploading-json-data)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do that by using **addOnProgressListener**

```
.addOnProgressListener(new OnProgressListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onProgress(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
            int progress = (int) ((100 * taskSnapshot.getBytesTransferred()) / taskSnapshot.getTotalByteCount());
            try {
                yourSeekBar.setProgress(progress);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    })
```

Comment: Dude you're God.Thank you so much.

Comment: Can you help me with this too? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45862094/displaying-progress-in-notification