# Displaying progress in notification

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

I am uploading a video to firebase and I want to show the status of the progress in both seekbar and in my notification. My seekbar behaves properly, but my notification with progress keeps showing download in progress status

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
     if (requestCode == RC_PHOTO_PICKER && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();

        // Get a reference to store file at chat_photos/<FILENAME>
        StorageReference photoRef = mChatPhotosStorageReference.child(selectedImageUri.getLastPathSegment());

        // Upload file to Firebase Storage
        photoRef.putFile(selectedImageUri)
                .addOnSuccessListener(this, new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                    public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                        // When the image has successfully uploaded, we get its download URL
                        //  progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        Uri downloadUrl = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl();

                        // Set the download URL to the message box, so that the user can send it to the database
                        Video video = new Video(downloadUrl.toString());
                        mMessagesDatabaseReference.push().setValue(video);

                    }
                }).addOnProgressListener(new OnProgressListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onProgress(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                final int progress = (int) ((100 * taskSnapshot.getBytesTransferred()) / taskSnapshot.getTotalByteCount());

                seekBar.setProgress(progress);
                final NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext())
                        .setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getApplicationContext(), R.color.colorPrimary))
                        .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                        .setContentText("Download in progress")
                        .setAutoCancel(true);

                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
                    notificationBuilder.setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_HIGH);
                }

                final NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)
                        getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

                new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        int incr;
                        // Do the "lengthy" operation 20 times
                        for (incr = progress; incr <= 100; incr++) {
                            // Sets the progress indicator to a max value, the
                            // current completion percentage, and "determinate"
                            // state
                            notificationBuilder.setProgress(100, incr, false);
                            // Displays the progress bar for the first time.
                            notificationManager.notify(id, notificationBuilder.build());
                            // Sleeps the thread, simulating an operation
                            // that takes time
                            try {
                                // Sleep for 5 seconds
                                Thread.sleep(5*1000);
                            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                Log.d(TAG, "sleep failure");
                            }
                        }
                        notificationBuilder.setContentText("Download complete")
                                // Removes the progress bar
                                .setProgress(0,0,false);
                        notificationManager.notify(id, notificationBuilder.build());
                      }

                    }
                // Starts the thread by calling the run() method in its Runnable
                ).start();
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Seekbar works fine, but notification with progress sometimes shows download complete even though file is not uploaded to firebase and after showing download complete, it agains shows the notification of in progress.What am i doing wrong? Please help. I already refer the following documentation & followed the steps but not able to figure it out why my notification with progress is behaving this way
https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/display-progress.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your Thread code is the main problem. The loops iterate after every 5 seconds. Hence your answer for "it agains shows the notification of in progress."
Remove the Thread from your code. It was just for example in [Developer Guide](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/display-progress.html#ActivityIndicator)

You can use `AsyncTask` to do this. Code is as follow:

```
private class YourTaskLoader extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
      notificationManager =(NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
      builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
      builder.setContentTitle("Picture upload")
                .setContentText("Uploading in progress")
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_backup);
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        UploadPicture();
        return null;
    }
}
```

Call your `AsyncTask` by following code when in need

```
new YourTaskLoader().execute();
```

and the code for `onProgress()` method
In that loop

```
builder.setProgress(100,progress,false);
notificationManager.notify(1001,builder.build());
```

After the loop is over Call the following lines so that the progress in the notification bar is removed.
You can add these lines in `onSuccess()` method.

```
builder.setContentText("Upload Complete")
       .setProgress(0,0,false);
notificationManager.notify(1001,builder.build());
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks ,i followed your advice.You got it right for the most part.I included the notification code also in doInBackgound. Now its working fine

Comment: @abu you are welcome. You can also initialize the notificationManager and builder inside onCreate, then there is no need to put this code in doInBackground.