# Android Progress Bar with percentage of image upload

Tags: android, image-uploading, android-progressbar

I am using google vision api in my code in Android studio and I'm sending it image from camera or gallery. Uploading image takes time, so I want the users of my app to have feedback about what's going on. Progress Bar with real time percentage of image upload is what I need. Here is my code for uploading image:

```
@SuppressLint("StaticFieldLeak")
private void callCloudVision(final Bitmap bitmap) throws IOException {

    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE);

    // Do the real work in an async task, because we need to use the network anyway
    new AsyncTask<Object, Integer, String>() {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Object... params) {
            try {
                HttpTransport httpTransport = AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport();
                JsonFactory jsonFactory = GsonFactory.getDefaultInstance();


                VisionRequestInitializer requestInitializer =
                        new VisionRequestInitializer(CLOUD_VISION_API_KEY) {
                            /**
                             * We override this so we can inject important identifying fields into the HTTP
                             * headers. This enables use of a restricted cloud platform API key.
                             */
                            @Override
                            protected void initializeVisionRequest(VisionRequest<?> visionRequest)
                                    throws IOException {
                                super.initializeVisionRequest(visionRequest);

                                String packageName = getPackageName();
                                visionRequest.getRequestHeaders().set(ANDROID_PACKAGE_HEADER, packageName);

                                String sig = PackageManagerUtils.getSignature(getPackageManager(), packageName);

                                visionRequest.getRequestHeaders().set(ANDROID_CERT_HEADER, sig);
                            }
                        };

                Vision.Builder builder = new Vision.Builder(httpTransport, jsonFactory, null);
                builder.setVisionRequestInitializer(requestInitializer);

                Vision vision = builder.build();

                BatchAnnotateImagesRequest batchAnnotateImagesRequest =
                        new BatchAnnotateImagesRequest();
                batchAnnotateImagesRequest.setRequests(new ArrayList<AnnotateImageRequest>() {{
                    AnnotateImageRequest annotateImageRequest = new AnnotateImageRequest();

                    // Add the image
                    Image base64EncodedImage = new Image();
                    // Convert the bitmap to a JPEG
                    // Just in case it's a format that Android understands but Cloud Vision
                    ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, byteArrayOutputStream);
                    byte[] imageBytes = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();

                    // Base64 encode the JPEG
                    base64EncodedImage.encodeContent(imageBytes);
                    annotateImageRequest.setImage(base64EncodedImage)   ;

                    // add the features we want
                    annotateImageRequest.setFeatures(new ArrayList<Feature>() {{
                        Feature labelDetection = new Feature();
                        labelDetection.setType("TEXT_DETECTION");
                        add(labelDetection);
                    }});

                    // Add the list of one thing to the request
                    add(annotateImageRequest);
                }});


                Vision.Images.Annotate annotateRequest =
                        vision.images().annotate(batchAnnotateImagesRequest);
                // Due to a bug: requests to Vision API containing large images fail when GZipped.
                annotateRequest.setDisableGZipContent(true);
                Log.d(TAG, "created Cloud Vision request object, sending request");


                BatchAnnotateImagesResponse response = annotateRequest.execute();
                ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

                return convertResponseToString(response);

            } catch (GoogleJsonResponseException e) {
                Log.d(TAG, "failed to make API request because " + e.getContent());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.d(TAG, "failed to make API request because of other IOException " +
                        e.getMessage());
            }
            getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE);
            return "Cloud Vision API request failed. Check logs for details.";

        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
            super.onProgressUpdate(values);

        }


        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            openOcrResultActivity(result);        
            getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE);
        }
    }.execute();
}
```

I searched for few days and I know that in `callCloudVision` function I need to call `publishProgress()`. `publishProgress` will trigger`onProgressUpdate(i)` and there I will get percent of upload as parameter (i) and increment `progressbar`. Something like this:

```
MyProgressBar.incrementProgressBy((values[0] * 2));
```

But I don't know how to get percentage of uploaded image in callCloudVision function.

Please help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to show progress bar status by percentage while uploading json data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37457152/how-to-show-progress-bar-status-by-percentage-while-uploading-json-data)

Comment: this is totally different way of uploading image than the way google cloud vision api works. Also, there is no answer in that question that solves the problem.